# Ajax.Request doesn't work with CORS in IE8/9, fails silently

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-9, prototypejs, xdomainrequest

I have a question about Prototype's handling of CORS with IE browsers < 10. I noticed that a call to Ajax.Request to a cross origin URL would fail silently in IE9, checking the access logs for the server it's clear that the request was never even made.

After some reading it seems that IE8/9 must use their own `XDomainRequest` object in order to enable CORS, however Prototype's `Ajax.getTransport` function returns the `XMLHttpRequest` object which I understand does not allow CORS in IE8/9?

[I have found a patch for jQuery](https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks/blob/master/src/xdr.js) for the same issue, which tells me this might also be an issue with Prototype, I just can't find anything posted about it.

I have implemented a bit of a hacky fix:

```
if (window.XDomainRequest) {
    // Use Microsoft XDR for IE8 and IE9
    var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
    xdr.open('POST', url);
    xdr.onload = function () {
        var data = xdr.responseText.evalJSON();
        callback_handler(data.domain);
    };
    setTimeout(function(){
        xdr.send();
    }, 0);
} else {
    new Ajax.Request(url,
        {
            method: 'post',
            onSuccess: function(response)
            {
                var data = response.responseText.evalJSON();
                callback_handler(data.domain);
            }
        }
    );
};
```

...but I was wondering if anyone (or Prototype itself) had a better solution?

Comment: There is a merged Pull Request that helps to make CORS requests work, here https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/pull/88. Its not in the the 1.7.1 release, but you can either build from github repo or use this unoffical build http://cdnadmin.freewaypro.com/libraries/16

Comment: Ah interesting! However, that pull request seems to be fixing an issue with Prototype and CORS in all browsers but not the IE8/9 issue which specifically relates the `XMLHttpRequest` object in those versions not being able to handle cross domain requests, and how Prototype doesn't seem to account for that.

Comment: Your right - I'll see if I can get a Pull Request together that handles the `XDomainRequest` object.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Ajax.getTransport](https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/master/src/prototype/ajax/ajax.js#L7-L11) method's source:

```
var Ajax = {
  getTransport: function() {
    return Try.these(
      function() {return new XMLHttpRequest()},
      function() {return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP')},
      function() {return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')}
    ) || false;
  }
}
```

You can see that `getTransport` will try to return a new instance of each of the listed transports. So, you can implement a polyfill that adds `XDomainRequest` beforehand.

```
var _getTransport = Ajax.getTransport;
Ajax.getTransport = function() {
    return Try.these(
        function() { return new XDomainRequest() },
        _getTransport
    ) || false;
};
```

If you insert this code somewhere between including prototype, and first using Ajax.Request, it should seamlessly use XDR where possible.

**N.B.** This is entirely untested and almost certainly has some edge cases - I'm not sure what XDR's behaviour is for same-domain requests.